# How to make NsPopover in Xcode 6.3 OS X10.10 in objective C

Tags: macos, nspopover

I am a new developer, I am trying to develop Nspopover on button click but I am not getting relevant resources so how should I do in XCode 6.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/Popover/Listings/MyWindowController_m.html

BTW it's faster if you search by yourself "nspopover site:developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode"

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSViewController *popoverViewController;

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  showPopoverAction:sender
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (IBAction)showPopoverAction:(id)sender
{
    [self createPopover];

    NSButton *targetButton = (NSButton *)sender;

    // configure the preferred position of the popover
    NSRectEdge prefEdge = popoverPosition.selectedRow;

    [self.myPopover showRelativeToRect:[targetButton bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:prefEdge];
}


// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  createPopover
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)createPopover
{
    if (self.myPopover == nil)
    {
        // create and setup our popover
        myPopover = [[NSPopover alloc] init];

        // the popover retains us and we retain the popover,
        // we drop the popover whenever it is closed to avoid a cycle
        //
        // use a different view controller content if normal vs. HUD appearance
        //

        self.myPopover.contentViewController = popoverViewController;

        // AppKit will close the popover when the user interacts with a user interface element outside the popover.
        // note that interacting with menus or panels that become key only when needed will not cause a transient popover to close.
        self.myPopover.behavior = NSPopoverBehaviorTransient;
    }
}
```